# Module integration with custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, module

so I am trying to integrate a custom module we purchased into a theme (free one) that we downloaded, but I really am hitting it hard here. Let me provide URL's before I continue explaining:

- [Theme] emthemes.com/responsive-magento-themes/em-titany.html
- [Module] webtexsoftware.com/baby-gift-registry-magento-extension
- [Module demo] 1.demo.webtexsoftware.com/

*I am sorry I cannot provide full links, I need reputation to add more than 1.*

So the problem is, that it appears the following module is designed to work with magento's **default** theme only, or at least that's what I think. At the demo page, you can see what is the end result. Link with javascript popup is automatically added into navigation (Baby registry).

Now, when I apply my custom theme to be loaded by default, everything works fine, except that I don't get to have my module's custom link. If I switch back to default theme, it all seems to be running smoothly.

Now, I want to say that I have little to no experience when it comes to magento development.

I've started reading lots of articles, and I've grasped a little how magento works, how configuration is being handled on load and so. There are some parts of the module that are being loaded correctly, but most of the files are just ignored, you can say. My guess would be, that my theme is overriding or like it's having higher priority to the module.

I'll provide part of the folder structure, because I believe it could come in handy for someone.

My module:

```
├── app
    │   ├── code
    │   │   └── local
    │   │       └── MagExt
    ├── design
    │   │   ├── adminhtml
    │   │   │   └── default
    │   │   │       └── default
    │   └── frontend
    │   │       └── default
    │   │           └── default
└── skin
└── frontend
    └── default
        └── default
```

My theme structure:

```
├── app/
    ├── design 
        ├── frontend
            ├── default
                ├── em0121
```

Now as I already said, configuration seems to be loaded correctly, but still having problems. For instance, there is main configuration file placed in `/layout/` which it seems to be working, since I am seeing the javascript and css files appended to my template, but the following line for example does not do anything:

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>sometemplate.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

And other stuff like that.

- My magento version is 1.9.1.0
- My module is written to support multiple versions, and the one I'm using is also for 1.9.x

Any kind of advice or tutorials to read would be highly valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento appearance work with package and themes, in the following way :

```
├── design 
    ├── frontend
        ├── base
            ├── default
            ├── theme1
            ├── theme2
            ├── ...
        ├── package
            ├── default
            ├── theme1
            ├── theme2
            ├── ...
```

When Magento render your theme, it will look for the layout and template files in your current theme directory. If they can not be found, then it will look for the files in the default theme of the same package. If it still can not be found, it will look for the files in the default theme of the base directory.

So if your module put its files in the default/default directory, you will be able to access it if your theme is in the default package, even if it's in another theme. And if you want to override this module, you can copy the files you want to override in your theme, and edit them. This way, the module can still be updated without loosing your modifications.

(It works the same for the skin folder)

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. I've already red the article about theme hierarchy. The configuration files of my module are being loaded properly, but the layout updates does not function like it was supposed to. They manage to add css and javascript files to my theme, but the reference blocks that need to replace some templates are not called/executed. Is there any way to find out the order of loading the xml files?